# ImageButton not displaying image after close and relaunch

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imagebutton

I need help. I am trying to load a picture selected from the phone gallery when the app launches.

I have an `ImageButton` x that displays a picture selected by the user from the phone's galley. So far so good right? Well yes but when I close and relaunch the app the image is not displayed by x and I have to select image from the gallery again.

I am getting the image back from the gallery in a data stream and using a `BitMap` to work with the `ImageButton`. I have tried `SharedPreferences`, saving and loading from source, no luck!

Comment: this may have to do with the activity life cycle,check http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html or you can have a value stored in the stored  preferences ,when the image is clicked and load in the oncreate according to that value

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have Activity A which starts activity B.

If you're pressing the Back button in Activity B without overriding it's functionality, the system will kill the current activity (B --> onPause > onStop > onDestroy) and return to the last one (A --> onRestart > onStart > onResume). See the [Activity Lifecycle](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/android-developer/attachments/2960d1328950749-android-activity-lifecycle-1.jpg) for a picture.

Pressing the Home button has a different effect where only onPause and onStop would be called (unless the operating system determines it needs the memory and decides to kill it, in which case it will go all the way back to onCreate).

Saving the URI to the selected Bitmap in the SharedPreferences is definitely a good way to go, though. Your issue just sounds like it's with the lifecycle.